# Meteor Autorun() not running when accessing collection.property

Tags: meteor

Something strange is going on; when I run the following code, it works:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  var room = Rooms.findOne({'room_id':Session.get('room_id')});
  // var p = room.room_id;
  console.log('autorun');
}
```

However, if I uncomment the `var p` line, it (the whole block) stops running. What's happening?

Comment: What do you mean by *stops running* ?. Does it throws any errors or the whole code block stops running?

Comment: The whole block does not get evaluated - it's not autorunning for some reason.

Comment: Can you put one `console.log` to the beginning of the function? Maybe there is some error thrown somewhere.

Comment: I tried putting another logging statement at the top of the block but that doesn't get run either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the depths of the Meteor.js documentation: "If the initial run of an autorun throws an exception, the computation is automatically stopped and won't be rerun."

On the first run of autorun, which is when the page is loaded, the database hasn't been loaded which throws an exception when you try to access `room.room_id`, and the autorun immediately stops from running again. Fixed by adding:

```
if (room) {
  console.log(room.room_id);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! In my autorun, I'm already checking for document.body, userId, firstRun and now finally, thanks to your answer, the var associated with my collection query @kennysong